# Why did Cutter betray Angier and lead Borden to kill him?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-prestige

Why did Cutter betray Angier and lead Borden to kill him Angier at the end of the movie? Angier's wife drowned, Borden's wife hanged, Fallon/Borden hanged. But Cutter had no motive to do any of this, unless he was in cahoots with Borden. But the movie had no indication of this.

Comment: Although not the same question, it does have answers [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9619/why-did-cutter-retell-the-sailor-story)

Answer (score 15):

My understanding was that Cutter start sympathizing with Borden for his  loss of life. Cutter was intially with Angier only, however  when he saw that Angier got one innocent man hanged and also took his daughter just for revenge. So he got disgusted. Also, he wanted to destroy that  machine because it was not magic trick but real dangerous magic/science leading to killing one person (Angiers clone) every night.

Same is told in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prestige_(film)) in this paragraph

> Cutter learns that Caldlow has bought all of Angier's equipment,
>   including the machine. He visits Lord Caldlow to plead for its
>   destruction. He recognizes Angier, who had admitted earlier that he
>   has always been Lord Caldlow (he had used the name Robert Angier to
>   spare his family the embarrassment of his theatrical career). Cutter
>   is disgusted with Angier for letting Borden hang and taking Borden's
>   daughter.

Comment: Then it's a big plot hole. It was never revealed how Cutter found out there was a twin. Angier showed Cutter the trick only after he was duped into meeting him, so he tells Cutter the truth. However at that point no one knows of the twin. So the reason is that Cutter is mad at Angier because he let someone die? That makes no sense because Borden killed 1) Julia 2) Sarah 3) turned Olivia 4) nearly destroyed Angier by sending him to America 5) Shot Cutter 6) Broke a random audiences fingers. Angier is letting justice be served. Cutter's involvement was just a penciled "the end."

Comment: Borden never intently killed anyone, it was Angier who become obessed with revenge because borden was not able to answer which know he tied. May be because borden tied his wife, but Angier asked fallon or vice versa. So he was not  sure which knot his twin tied .

Comment: @mang108 "plot hole" is not the same as "not explained". A plot hole is a contradiction in the plot, rather than the omission of events that happened off-camera inbetween on-camera events. Exactly _because_ Cutter shows up with Borden's brother, the viewer can infer that Cutter has been actively making amends. What he exactly did is not relevant to the story, the only relevant piece of information is that he is now aware of the twin brother's existence, and clearly working together with the twin brother.

Comment: @mang108 While Borden played a part in the deaths of Julia and Sarah, it's simplistic to say he "killed" them. For both of them, it was ultimately their choice, Sarah to commit suicide and Julia to take part in a dangerous trick.

Answer (score 2):

Cutter just feels betrayed that Angier had gone to extreme lengths for his Transported Man trick which is not a trick at all but real science was involved where a clone of Angier gets killed every night. Cutter knows this since he has seen the old theater dump where the walls were lined with glass tanks of decomposed clones. Throughout the movie we have seen that cutter believed in a good magic trick but isn't very approving of Angier's obsession (even when he breaks the news of going to meet Tesla). Adding to this are the other facts that Angier framed an innocent Borden and took away his child from him. So Cutter had all good reasons to side with Borden even though he dint know about Fallon yet.

Answer (score 0):

My comprehension of this is Cutter learned about the inhumane things which Angeir was doing- making clones of himself, and if you remember the scene where cutter says - "I once told you about a sailor, he told me drowning was like going home, I lied it was agony ". It clearly implies of all the murders Angeir was doing of his clones as every time new clone didn't know about the agony in drowning, it would have been considered Sacrifice if he had known the pain in dying but he was willingly killing himself. That's why Cutter helped Borden killing Angeir, In addition, separating daughter from father is also a considerable factor.